# war архив в консоли windows

Tags: java, war

Здравствуйте!
Собираю архив war в консоли windows.
d:\work\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin>jar -cvf my.war my.html
Если файл my.html лежит прямо в java d bin - тогда собирает.
но это не правильно - помещать рабочие файлы в java в bin
Если поместить my.html в папку например d:\projects
и выполнить
d:\projects>set java_home d:\work\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin
указываю путь к jdk 
d:\projects>jar -cvf my.war my.html
тогда выдаёт ошибку
my.html : no such file or directory
added manifest

Как решить эту проблему.
Для других задач использую netbeans. но здесь надо использовать консоль. (windows)

Answer (score 2):

Приветствую.
Попробуйте использовать средства сборки maven или gradle, при помощи которых можно собрать любой нужный нам архив, в том числе war. Подробная документация от NetBeans - https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/maven-entapp_ru.html#intro